# How to Load Association Before Detaching Objects in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datacontext

I am working with a parent and child table in Entity Framework.  The parent table is Invoices and the child table is InvoiceLineItems.  Each row in the invoice table naturally represents an Invoice.  And, each row in the InvoiceLineItems table represents one line of detail for the invoice (i.e. item information such as item name, price, etc...).  The InvoiceLineItem table has a foreign key to the Invoice table so that there is a collection of InvoiceLineItems on each Invoice object.

Everything is working perfectly but, I have one issue.  At one point in our code, we build a list of Invoice objects in a detached state.  Then, we insert all of the objects into a database using an EF data context (now they are attached to session).  Then, we are attempting to detach the Invoice objects from this session so that we can insert the invoices into another database with a new EF context.  When we detach the invoices, all of the InvoiceLineItem collections are empty.  Is there a way that we can detach the Invoices and force the bags to load before the first session is closed so that they will be available to the second data context?  A code sample is below to demonstrate what we are attempting to accomplish.

```
// Get a list of invoices from Quickbooks
List<Invoice> qbInvoices = GetInvoicesFromQuickbooks(currentThread);

SaveInvoicesToLocalDatabase(dbContextLocal, qbInvoices, currentThread);

// Detach the Invoices from above context so that we can insert them into
// the second database using the new context below.
// NOTE: All Invoice.InvoiceLineItem collections are empty
//       How do we force InvoiceLineItems to load???
qbInvoices = dbContextLocal.Invoices.AsNoTracking().ToList();
dbContextLocal.Dispose();

// This only saves rows to Invoices table (i.e. no InvoiceLineItems are saved)
SaveInvoicesToRemoteDatabase(dbContextWeb, qbInvoices, currentThread);
dbContextWeb.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, the original disconnected Invoice entities you create have the child line items, so you really just want to unhook them and move them to the other context.  I'm not sure, but `AsNoTracking` may be doing another fetch or otherwise creating new instances of the entities you've added rather than reusing the original instances.

I'd suggest casting your `DbContext` down to an `ObjectContext` and calling the `Detach` method on your invoices so they can be moved to a new context.

**Instead of:**

```
qbInvoices = dbContextLocal.Invoices.AsNoTracking().ToList();
dbContextLocal.Dispose();
```

**Do:**

```
var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;
foreach(var invoice in qbInvoices) {
    objectContext.Detach(invoice);
}
```